# pyqt5でkeyPressEventがうまくいかない

Tags: python3, pyqt5

pyqt5でグラフを描いた時に、特定のキーを押したときにアクションを起こすようにしたいです。下は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        #FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def plot_figure(self):
        pass

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            print("g")
        else:
            print("G")


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)     



class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが作成されます。
[image: 画像]
ここで右矢印キーを押したときに「ｇ」とプリントされるように書いてみたつもりですが、実際はキーを押しても何も反応しません。特にエラーは吐いていません。どのように直せばよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デフォルト状態の時：
[How PyQt5 keyPressEvent works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45308101/9014308)

`def keyPressEvent(self,event):` の処理を `class Main(QDialog):` の方に移動してください。

---

特定の部品でのみ処理したい時：
[keyPressEvent no reaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22169216/9014308)
[PyQt5 processes MousePressEvent but not KeyPressEvent [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50804987/9014308)

> したがって、`self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)`という行を使用してフォーカスポリシーを追加すると問題が解決します。

該当部品(質問の場合は`class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):`)の`__init__`等に`self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)`を追加してください。

---

いずれも文字はコンソールの方に出ます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。下のコードの様に書き直し、無事動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

修正したコードです

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets,QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.plot_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        #FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def plot_figure(self):
        pass

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            print("g")
        else:
            print("G")


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyStaticMplCanvas,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

    def plot_figure(self):
        x=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)
        y=np.sin(x)
        self.axes.plot(x,y,"-")
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_xlim(0,2*np.pi)     



class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('plot')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()

    app.exec_()
```